# How can I change audio sources with three.js' THREE.AudioLoader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-audio-api

I'm working on a city soundscape for a project (live model here: https://drush92.github.io/nftaudiometaverse/nftropolis/ *takes a while to load*)

I have loaded some audio using:

```
let audioFile = 'audio/police_officer.wav';
// load a sound and set it as the PositionalAudio object's buffer
const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load( audioFile, function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setRefDistance( 0.1 );
  sound.setMaxDistance( 0.01 );
  sound.setRollOffFactor( 0.1 );
});

// create an object for the sound to play from
const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.001, 0.001, 0.001 );
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff2200 } );
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material );
mesh.position.set(-78, 0.11, -10);
scene.add( mesh );

// finally add the sound to the mesh
mesh.add( sound );
```

I have a simple dialogue with the police officer and when a button is pressed I want to audio file to be switched to the next part of the conversation.

and i have the following in my animate function:

```
const distanceToCharacter = camera.position.distanceTo(characterPosition);
if (distanceToCharacter < distanceToShow) {
    nearCharacter.style.display = 'block';
    sound.play();
    sound.setLoop(false);
  } else {
    nearCharacter.style.display = 'none';
    characterRun.style.display = 'none';
    characterPayToll.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

so i have a button that triggers all this:

```
function changeAudio() {
  console.log('Button clicked!');

  // stop the audio playback
  sound.stop();

  // toggle between the two audio files
  audioFile = 'audio/siren.wav';

  // load the new audio file and set it as the PositionalAudio object's buffer
  audioLoader.load( audioFile, function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setRefDistance( 0.1 );
    sound.setMaxDistance( 0.01 );
    sound.setRollOffFactor( 0.1 );
  });
}

// register the event listener for the click event
const selectCharacterRun = document.getElementById('select-character-run');
selectCharacterRun.addEventListener('click', changeAudio);
```

currently when the button is pressed, the original 'police_officer.wav' keeps playing and the second file 'siren.wav' plays after.

I want it to switch as soon as the button is pressed.

I was thinking it could be a problem with the fact I have source being played in the animated function....?